# Making inputs that update props onChange when using create-react-app structure?

Tags: javascript, html, onchange, create-react-app

I am making a web based calculator tool which will update the graph in real time as the four input fields are altered by the user.

The problem is, I do not understand props well enough to do it. And I am getting all kinds of errors for something that should only be 3 lines of code (maybe more if i cannot update all the this.income. simultaneously.

It is also further complicated by the props->render->return structure of Create-react-app since basically there is a js area and an html area.

Note: Some of the code below may be redundant such as the const props, since I am using this. instead.

[This is what it looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcVkz.png)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Collapse,  Navbar, Form,  NavbarToggler,    NavbarBrand,    Nav,    
NavItem,    NavLink,    Container,    Row,  Col,  Jumbotron,  Button,  
ButtonToolbar    } from 'reactstrap';
import { zingchart }from 'zingchart';
import {core as Core} from 'zingchart-react';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);

      //  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

  //These may not be needed:
        const trd = 0;
        const itr = 7;
        const lit = 6;
        const tei = 4;


        //this array of props keep track of values:
        this.income = {trd:8,itr:8,lit:8,tei:8};
        //this array sends values to the graph:
        this.formula = { a: ((this.income.lit*this.income.trd)*(1- 
        this.income.itr)), b: (this.income.lit*this.trd), c: this.income.tei}

        //Logic for Graph:
        //a = (lit * trd) * 1 - itr
        //b = lit * trd
        //c = tei
  }

        // function updateAField(modifiable,goalValue){
        //   modifiable = goalValue;
        // };


  render() {
    var myConfig = {
    // This is just the irrelevant graph info - it has been shortened for 
    // readability on stackOverflow
               type: "bar3d",
               "stacked": true,
               series : [{values : [this.formula.a, this.formula.b, 
               this.formula.c]}]
             };

    return (

      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <div className="App">
                  <header className="App-header">

                          <header className="App-form">
                          <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                                    <form>
                                    <label class="title" >Income 
 Distribution</label>
                                    <br/>
                                    <br/>
                                    <br/><label>Traditional/Roth Dist% 
 </label>
              <input id="trd" type="text" value={this.income.trd} onChange= 
              {this.income.trd.bind(this) } required />
                                    <br/><label>Income Tax Rate %</label>
              <input id="itr" type="text" value={this.income.itr} onChange={e 
              => this.onChange(e.target.value)} required />
                                    <br/><label>Life Insurance Total 
 $</label>
              <input id="lit" type="text" value={this.income.lit} onChange={e 
              => this.onChange(e.target.value)} required/>
                                    <br/><label>Tax Exempt Income $</label>
              <input id="tei" type="text" value={this.income.tei} onChange={e 
               => this.onChange(e.target.value)} required/>
                                    </form>
                                  <br/>
                            </header>
                    </header>
                </div>
              </div>
                  <div class="column">
                  <img src="./bws.jpg" className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                  <p>Define Your Future</p>
                  <Core id="myChart" height="400" width="800" data={myConfig} 
  />
                  <a className="App-link"href=""target="_blank"rel="noopener 
  noreferrer">Return to BWS</a>
                  </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
 }

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are missing is the idea of [`state`](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) in React. Components will only re-render when one of three things happen:

1. Props change (abstracted into `shouldComponentUpdate`)
2. State changes (abstracted into `shouldComponentUpdate`)
3. A call to `this.forceUpdate`

Anything that you expect to be changed in the component that should impact what is rendered when it changes needs to be stored in state. Right now after your initial render your component will never update again since you never change state and you never change the props being passed in by the parent.

```
import { PureComponent } from 'react';

class MyComponent extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    initialValue: PropTypes.number,
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      valueThatChanges: props.initialValue;
    };
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ valueThatChanges: calculateValue(event) });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.valueThatChanges} />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Forgive me but I'm a novice. So in the render, I should have <input ... value={this.income.xxx}onClick={this.income.forceUpdate}/>  ?

Comment: @MarkWagner I've added a very basic example of how state is used in React to my answer. You should be able to modify your component from there

Comment: Thank you! I think your answer is even more simple/smooth than mine but I finally solved it thanks to your help.

Comment: note that this is actually incorrect. components will not rerender when the props change. what happens is that the parent (who probably owns the state of the props) rerendered due to a state change, which triggers a rerender of the entire component tree below that. doesnt matter if props changed or not. it only partially appies when using `React.memo`.

Answer (score 0):

This was what finally worked. I used it for all four variables!

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
                      //this props array keeps track of values and contains 
 placeholders:
                      this.state = {trd:3,itr:30,lit:1329454,tei:66473};
                     }

      //this method updates it's target to what is in the field
        changeField(prp,id) {
          let val = document.getElementById([id]).value;
          this.setState(prevState => ({ [prp]: val }));
          }


<input id="a" type="text" value={this.state.trd} onChange={() => 
this.changeField('trd','a')}/>
```